# SP 2013 Workflow to generate Word document that contains all items in one custom list

Tags: 2013, workflow

I have set up a workflow that can generate a Word document for one item in a custom list.

I'd like to add a button to have the workflow add all items selected in the custom list and put them into the Word document - is there a way to loop through the custom list and add them to the Word document? Or is there a way to click on a button and all items in the view are put into Word document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no OOTB way to achieve this.

If you want to implement this you would need to take a closer look at the openXML API which allows you to create office documents. This is custom code, so you need to move it into a webservice. This webservice can then be called from a SP2013 workflow.

Creating documents is a "long running task" so consider that this webservice should make a callback once done, and not let WFM wait on the result of this action.

Hope this helps

Edit:
OpenXML SDK Starting point: https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2014/06/25/open-xml-sdk-goes-open-source/

Add custom webservice to workflows
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/working-with-web-services-in-sharepoint-workflows-using-sharepoint-designer

Comment: Thank you.  I'll look into this.  I haven't done that before. Is there any documentation or examples I could see that you would recommend?